# Refresh Power BI with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I would like to know if I can use PowerShell to refresh data in Power BI? I am not using the publish option, but am instead using an Excel document from a share drive.

Answer (score 2):

## This opens the report to be refreshed.

C:\Reports\Templates\Sensor_Exporter\Master8.pbix

Start-Sleep -s 20
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic");

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Master8 - Power BI Desktop");

Start-Sleep -s 5

## Acts as alt+H

$wshell.SendKeys("%H R");

Start-Sleep -s 2

## Sends R for refresh

$wshell.SendKeys("r")

Answer (score 1):

> I am not using the publish option, but am instead using an Excel document from a share drive.

Due to the above quote, I will assume that you are asking is it possible to refresh a pbix file, which you view in Power BI Desktop, and not how to refresh a report published to Power BI online.

No, Power BI Desktop can't be automated with PowerShell. You have to open the report in Power BI Desktop and click `Refresh` command in the ribbon:

[image]

If you want to use PowerShell to refresh this report, you must publish it to Power BI Online and use [Refresh Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset) or [Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) from [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to refresh the dataset. You can do this by installing [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps):

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Scope CurrentUser
```

And then login into Power BI and call the method you want, e.g.:

```
Login-PowerBI
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/gggggggg-gggg-gggg-gggg-gggggggggggg/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes' -Method Post
```

You must provide actual group ID an dataset ID in the url above.